# How can I extract the value of a variable and re-use that value until it is overwritten

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website which essentially acts as a blog / photo gallery. It comprises PHP and MYSQL.
My objective is to be able to set an image on my homeimage dynamically. I have set up a form which posts a variable (which contains the relevent image filename) to my homepage file. I pick this up using the $_POST method. This works fine, but only until I refresh the homepage at which point the variable is no longer there and so, understandably, the image is no longer called. Can anyone explain how I can store the variable value i.e. the image filename, so that it can be used until such time as it is overwritten by a new image. I have tried setting up a function that returns the value, but I can't seem to hold on to it!! Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: As you're using a database (MySQL) why not store the value in your database? Then you only need to post it once

Comment: I think you're right - just need to figure out the detail. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can do multiple things :

- Store it using MySQL. Create a table that will named "configuration" for example, with one field named "homepageImage" for example. When you want to modify the image on the homepage, just update this field. When you want to get the image, just query this table and fetch this field.
- Store it in a file on your server. You just have to overwrite the file with the new filename inside it when you want to change the image. Fetch the content of the file when you want to display the image
- Create a symbolic link (pointing to the right image), and update the link every time you want to change the image. When you want to display the image, just put the name of the link in your img tag

Comment: I think the database route is favourite. Thanks for your response.

Comment: This was my first question - I'm not sure how to accept a response, can you direct me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use $_SESSION['some_variable'] = some value;

Later put 'if($_SESSION['some_variable'] = some value)' condition and display the image.

After the job done (if you need your visitors to do something) then distroy session.

session_destroy();

Comment: My understanding of Sessions is that the value would only be held for the duration of a particular users "session", and it would not apply to all users accessing the site.

Comment: @Kirs Sudh I had this understanding of the problem first, but I think Brian wants the modification he makes to be visible for all users, so sessions are not suitable for that.

Comment: Thats right, sessions works for individual visitors. @Brian , how does the image-file variable overwritten in your code? Can you put your function here, so that we could look at it and find out the positive out come.

Comment: I've decided to set up a new field in my database called "home_image", which I'll add to my photograph table. Thanks for your help.